# Filter d3.s to show specific data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can d3.js be used to filter data to only show specific items in the data?

For example if I have a dataset as follows:

```
timestamp,location,price,FirstName,LastName
1/6/2014 7:28,Brew've Been Served,11.34,Edvard,Vann
1/6/2014 7:34,Hallowed Grounds,52.22,Hideki,Cocinaro
1/6/2014 7:35,Brew've Been Served,8.33,Stenig,Fusil
1/6/2014 7:36,Hallowed Grounds,16.72,Birgitta,Frente
1/6/2014 7:37,Brew've Been Served,4.24,Sven,Flecha
1/6/2014 7:38,Brew've Been Served,4.17,Cornelia,Lais
1/6/2014 7:42,Coffee Cameleon,28.73,Linnea,Bergen
1/6/2014 7:43,Brew've Been Served,9.6,Mat,Bramar
1/6/2014 7:43,Brew've Been Served,16.9,Brand,Tempestad
1/6/2014 7:47,Hallowed Grounds,16.53,Emile,Arpa
1/6/2014 7:48,Hallowed Grounds,10.66,Kare,Orilla
1/6/2014 7:49,Coffee Cameleon,8.39,Bertrand,Ovan
1/6/2014 7:52,Brew've Been Served,32.83,Hennie,Osvaldo
1/6/2014 7:54,Hallowed Grounds,16.88,Nils,Calixto
1/6/2014 7:54,Coffee Cameleon,11.86,Adra,Nubarron
1/6/2014 7:54,Hallowed Grounds,32.93,Rachel,Pantanal
1/6/2014 7:55,Hallowed Grounds,8.05,Lucas,Alcazar
1/6/2014 7:55,Brew've Been Served,3.67,Varja,Lagos
1/6/2014 7:59,Brew've Been Served,8.88,Inga,Ferro
1/6/2014 8:00,Brew've Been Served,4.27,Ruscella,Mies Haber
1/6/2014 8:00,Hallowed Grounds,9.69,Anda,Ribera
1/6/2014 8:01,Hallowed Grounds,10.07,Lidelse,Dedos
1/6/2014 8:06,Brew've Been Served,18.24,Loreto,Bodrogi
1/6/2014 8:06,Brew've Been Served,15.58,Minke,Mies
1/6/2014 8:07,Brew've Been Served,5.66,Felix,Resumir
1/6/2014 8:14,Coffee Cameleon,3.2,Carla,Forluniau
1/6/2014 8:16,Brew've Been Served,14.97,Kanon,Herrero
```

Can I draw a Scatter graph to only render circles for a FirstName 'Edward'?

I know how to create a scatter graph for a data but not how to filter it or if it can be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But can you paste your scatter plot code?

You can easily filter your data selection, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter

Comment: See: http://plnkr.co/edit/az5fyMNtvZXwJUQw1oM6?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.filter(function(d){return d.name.substring(0,6) === 'Edward'})` to your data array

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Here is a link to a plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/az5fyMNtvZXwJUQw1oM6?p=preview It currently shows all price values for all names. Can I get it to show price values for only dpecific nameceg FirstName: 'Edward'?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jREgRAc5s6vGxvKNXhNQ?p=preview (I used "Valeri" as there was no data for an "Edward")

Comment: Did you add just this: 
        .data(data.filter(function(d){ return d.FirstName.substring(0, 6) === 'Valeri'}))

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/dysQsllarAHpe2xyFs7B. I added `data = data.filter(function(d) { … });`, but @paul was faster

Comment: Do I have yo have fixed numbers of characters for the substring(0, 6)? I wanted to use a select menu to change the names on change of the slect menu. And not all names a the same length

Comment: You could use `.startsWith()` but that would only work in Chrome or Firefox. There are lots of examples of how to implement it yourself though, here's one: http://www.moreofless.co.uk/javascript-string-startswith-endswith/

Comment: Or, better still, just use `d.FirstName === "Valeri"` or `d.FirstName === "Paul"` or `d.FirstName === someVariable`

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Do you know best practice to get the current value of select menu with d3?

Comment: `d3.select("#objectID").node().value;` where `objectID` is the id of the select element